# Typescript custom errors in RESTful API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, error-handling

I have a code sniped from another project with custom errors in a RESTful API. This all worked fine until i refactored it to typescript. I did not understand how the error construktor works and *this.response* is not know in this scope.

**How i throw this error**

```
async function authenticate(request, response, next) {
    if(!request.body.email) {
        return next(new ErrorREST(Errors.BadRequest, "User name missing."));
    }
}
```

**error.js**

```js
const Errors = {
  BadRequest: {
    status: 400,
    message: "Request has wrong format."
  },
  Unauthorized: {
    status: 401,
    message: "Authentication credentials not valid."
  },
  Forbidden: {
    status: 403,
    message: "You're missing permission to execute this request."
  }
}

class ErrorREST extends Error {
  constructor(type, detail = undefined, ...args) {
    super(...args);

    if (typeof type !== 'object') {
      return new Error("You need to provide the error type.");
    }

    this.response = type;

    if (detail !== undefined) {
      this.response.detail = detail;
    }
  }
}
```

I have not found a similar solution. This solution provides predefined errors with additional custom messages.

Comment: It's not obvious what the issue is here. The `type` parameter needs have a type of `{ status: number, message: string}`. If not that, what is your question?

Comment: This is a good hint, but the main problem was this.response is not known in this scope. And because I don't know how this works in JavaScript i cant fix it in typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript create this.response at the moment you call it. So i create this field and typecript knew it.

Second problem was, i defined my routes in the app.ts after my error handling.

**error.ts**

```
const Errors = {
  BadRequest: {
    status: 400,
    message: "Request has wrong format."
  },
  Unauthorized: {
    status: 401,
    message: "Authentication credentials not valid."
  },
  Forbidden: {
    status: 403,
    message: "You're missing permission to execute this request."
  }
}

export class ErrorREST extends Error {
   public response: { status: number; message: string; detail: string };

    constructor(error: { status: number, message: string }, detail: string = undefined, ...args) {
       super(...args);
       this.response = {status: error.status, message: error.message, detail: detail};
   }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
 this.express.use('/api/users', usersRouter);

 this.express.use(function (error, request, response, next) {

      logRequest(console.error, request);
      console.error("ERROR OCCURRED:");
      console.error(error);

   if (error == null || error.response == null) {//error is not a custom error
      error = new ErrorREST(Errors.InternalServerError);
   } 

   response.status(error.response.status).send(error.response);
```

**return your error to user**

```
return next(new ErrorREST(Errors.Unauthorized));
return next(new ErrorREST(Errors.Unauthorized), "Authentication credentials not valid.");
```

[image: Custom RestError in Insomnia]